# Riemann Sum - correct formula for an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

Which one of these is correct, are both of these right? 
$$\Delta x_i = (x_i-x_{i-1}) $$

$$ \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{\|x\| \rightarrow 0} \ \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x_i $$

---

$$ \int_{x_0}^{x_n} f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow ∞} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x_i $$

Surely this one has an infinite upper bound and does not express the number of partitions going towards infinity. Which notation is correct to express the Riemann Sum in terms of an integral, i think i have confused my self. I have hardly done any calculus just so you know.

Comment: Both are flawed when stated without the explanations that go with them.

Comment: Riemann integral is not simply the limit of sequence. If you want to fully regard Riemann integral in the sense of limit, you need a generalized notion of sequence, namely [*net*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). In this case, you can consider the net $\{S(f,\Pi)\}_{\Pi\in\mathcal{P}}$ of Riemann sums over the set $$\mathcal{P}=\bigg\{\Pi=\{x_0,\xi_1,x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1},\xi_n,x_n\}:\begin{array}{cc}a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=b,\\\forall i:\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\end{array}\bigg\}$$ of all *tagged partitions* on $[a, b]$ endowed with the partial order as refinement.